# Using fs.extra copyRecursive gives a "TypeError: forEachAsync is not a function" error and I can't fix it

Tags: node.js, express, router, fs-extra

My code is :
http://pastebin.com/rCy4wSUK

As soon as this function is called by router it prints 
"done copying contents of clean base into temp" and then error which is here:
http://pastebin.com/UxEu4PaS

So at least it is not giving an error in copying but what is causing it to throw this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the fs.extra module has not installed completely and is missing a dependency. Your code runs fine for me with a fresh `npm install fs.extra q`

Remove your `node_modules` folder and re-run `npm install` (if your dependencies are listed in `package.json`) or `npm install fs.extra q` (if they are not).

Comment: that worked briefly but I discovered when I would install other npm modules that use walk and foreachasync module like the "@angular/common" then it would break again. Both "fs.extra" and "@angular/common" install walk@2.2.1. However if you do "npm install --save walk foreachasync" separately it will install the walk@2.3.9 foreachasync@5.0.5. After that I am not seeing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue on case-insensitive filesystems in projects that require different versions of walk that depend on forEachAsync@2.x and foreachasync@3.x. Because the casing but not name of foreachasync changed across versions, it seems like it might be confusing npm and not properly installing the right versions.

I was able to fix this in our project by explicitly depending on `foreachasync@^3.0.0`.