# error creating a git repository with nodegit

Tags: node.js, nodegit

```
var nodegit = require("nodegit");
var path = require("path");
var fse = require("fs-extra");
var repoDir = "../git_repositories/";

var repository;
var index;

//eventually need to pass in user here for some metadata (author/committor info)
createGitRepository = (user, repositoryName) => {
  var newRepoDir = repoDir.concat(repositoryName);
  var fileName = repositoryName.concat(".txt");
  var fileContent = repositoryName.concat("DEFAULT CONTENTS");
  fse.ensureDir(path.resolve(__dirname, newRepoDir))
    .then(function () {
      return nodegit.Repository.init(path.resolve(__dirname, newRepoDir), 0);
    })
    .then(function (repo) {
      repository = repo;
      return fse.writeFile(path.join(repository.workdir(), fileName), fileContent);
    })
    .then(function () {
      return repository.refreshIndex();
    })
    .then(function (idx) {
      index = idx;
    })
    .then(function () {
      return index.addByPath(fileName);
    })
    .then(function () {
      return index.write();
    })
    .then(function () {
      return index.writeTree();
    })
    .then(function (oid) {
      var author = nodegit.Signature.now("Zaphod Beeblebrox",
        "zaphod@gmail.com");
      var committer = nodegit.Signature.now("Ford Prefect",
        "ford@github.com");

      // Since we're creating an inital commit, it has no parents. Note that unlike
      // normal we don't get the head either, because there isn't one yet.
      var commit = repository.createCommit("HEAD", author, committer, "message", oid, []);
      return commit;
    })
    .done(function (commitId) {
      console.log("New Commit: ", commitId);
    });
}

addAndCommit = (fileName, fileContent) => {
  nodegit.Repository.open(path.resolve(__dirname, "../.git"))
    .then(function (repoResult) {
      repo = repoResult;
      return fse.ensureDir(path.join(repo.workdir(), directoryName));
    }).then(function () {
      return fse.writeFile(path.join(repo.workdir(), fileName), fileContent);
    })
    .then(function () {
      return fse.writeFile(
        path.join(repo.workdir(), directoryName, fileName),
        fileContent
      );
    })
    .then(function () {
      return repo.refreshIndex();
    })
    .then(function (indexResult) {
      index = indexResult;
    })
    .then(function () {
      // this file is in the root of the directory and doesn't need a full path
      return index.addByPath(fileName);
    })
    .then(function () {
      // this file is in a subdirectory and can use a relative path
      return index.addByPath(path.posix.join(directoryName, fileName));
    })
    .then(function () {
      // this will write both files to the index
      return index.write();
    })
    .then(function () {
      return index.writeTree();
    })
    .then(function (oidResult) {
      oid = oidResult;
      return nodegit.Reference.nameToId(repo, "HEAD");
    })
    .then(function (head) {
      return repo.getCommit(head);
    })
    .then(function (parent) {
      var author = nodegit.Signature.now("Scott Chacon",
        "schacon@gmail.com");
      var committer = nodegit.Signature.now("Scott A Chacon",
        "scott@github.com");

      return repo.createCommit("HEAD", author, committer, "message", oid, [parent]);
    })
    .done(function (commitId) {
      console.log("New Commit: ", commitId);
    });
}
module.exports = {
  createGitRepository,
  addAndCommit
}
```

it creates the folder, file and repository successfully but throws error.  Im not sure though what the error is indicating exactly and i cant figure it out stepping through the code?

> TEST1 TypeError:
> fse.ensureDir(...).then(...).then(...).then(...).then(...).then(...).then(...).then(...).then(...).done
> is not a function
> at Object.createGitRepository (c:\CodeRepos\work\github\aa\ac\service\GitService.js:50:6)
> at createRepository (c:\CodeRepos\work\github\aa\ac\controllers\repository-ctrl.js:55:33)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\CodeRepos\work\github\aa\ac\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at next (c:\CodeRepos\work\github\aa\ac\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
> at Route.dispatch (c:\CodeRepos\work\github\aa\ac\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\CodeRepos\work\github\aa\ac\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at c:\CodeRepos\work\github\aa\ac\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
> at Function.process_params (c:\CodeRepos\work\github\aa\ac\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
> at next (c:\CodeRepos\work\github\aa\ac\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
> at Function.handle (c:\CodeRepos\work\github\aa\ac\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
> at router (c:\CodeRepos\work\github\aa\ac\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\CodeRepos\work\github\aa\ac\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at trim_prefix (c:\CodeRepos\work\github\aa\ac\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
> at c:\CodeRepos\work\github\aa\ac\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
> at Function.process_params (c:\CodeRepos\work\github\aa\ac\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
> at next (c:\CodeRepos\work\github\aa\ac\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)

seems to happen on the line:

return nodegit.Repository.init(path.resolve(__dirname, newRepoDir), 0);

I feel like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44054844/530933) is possibly related but it didnt fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

needed to change .done to .then at the end

```
var nodegit = require("nodegit");
var path = require("path");
var fse = require("fs-extra");
var repoDir = "../git_repositories/";

var repository;
var index;

//eventually need to pass in user here for some metadata (author/committor info)
createGitRepository = (user, repositoryName) => {
  var newRepoDir = repoDir.concat(repositoryName);
  var fileName = repositoryName.concat(".txt");
  var fileContent = repositoryName.concat("DEFAULT CONTENTS");
  fse.ensureDir(path.resolve(__dirname, newRepoDir))
    .then(function () {
      return nodegit.Repository.init(path.resolve(__dirname, newRepoDir), 0);
    })
    .then(function (repo) {
      repository = repo;
      return fse.writeFile(path.join(repository.workdir(), fileName), fileContent);
    })
    .then(function () {
      return repository.refreshIndex();
    })
    .then(function (idx) {
      index = idx;
    })
    .then(function () {
      return index.addByPath(fileName);
    })
    .then(function () {
      return index.write();
    })
    .then(function () {
      return index.writeTree();
    })
    .then(function (oid) {
      var author = nodegit.Signature.now("Zaphod Beeblebrox",
        "zaphod@gmail.com");
      var committer = nodegit.Signature.now("Ford Prefect",
        "ford@github.com");

      // Since we're creating an inital commit, it has no parents. Note that unlike
      // normal we don't get the head either, because there isn't one yet.
      var commit = repository.createCommit("HEAD", author, committer, "message", oid, []);
      return commit;
    })
    .then(function (commitId) {
      console.log("New Commit: ", commitId);
    });
}

addAndCommit = (fileName, fileContent) => {
  nodegit.Repository.open(path.resolve(__dirname, "../.git"))
    .then(function (repoResult) {
      repo = repoResult;
      return fse.ensureDir(path.join(repo.workdir(), directoryName));
    }).then(function () {
      return fse.writeFile(path.join(repo.workdir(), fileName), fileContent);
    })
    .then(function () {
      return fse.writeFile(
        path.join(repo.workdir(), directoryName, fileName),
        fileContent
      );
    })
    .then(function () {
      return repo.refreshIndex();
    })
    .then(function (indexResult) {
      index = indexResult;
    })
    .then(function () {
      // this file is in the root of the directory and doesn't need a full path
      return index.addByPath(fileName);
    })
    .then(function () {
      // this file is in a subdirectory and can use a relative path
      return index.addByPath(path.posix.join(directoryName, fileName));
    })
    .then(function () {
      // this will write both files to the index
      return index.write();
    })
    .then(function () {
      return index.writeTree();
    })
    .then(function (oidResult) {
      oid = oidResult;
      return nodegit.Reference.nameToId(repo, "HEAD");
    })
    .then(function (head) {
      return repo.getCommit(head);
    })
    .then(function (parent) {
      var author = nodegit.Signature.now("Scott Chacon",
        "schacon@gmail.com");
      var committer = nodegit.Signature.now("Scott A Chacon",
        "scott@github.com");

      return repo.createCommit("HEAD", author, committer, "message", oid, [parent]);
    })
    .done(function (commitId) {
      console.log("New Commit: ", commitId);
    });
}
module.exports = {
  createGitRepository,
  addAndCommit
}
```